# macbook air early 2008 (original) 13inch: 45 W magsafe charger

Tags: macbook-pro, magsafe, charger

[here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700)
Apple has two slightly different adapters called magsafe L 45W: the first one is recommended for my model, but then on the store they only sell the 2nd one: will this be fully compatible with my laptop?

where (besides amazon) will it be possible to buy just the cord that goes from charger to laptop?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Any Magsafe adapter >45W (which is all) will be OK. Magsafe2 use a different connector and can't be used.

Comment: @Milliways I agree it has to be 45W. If you look at the page, there are two slightly differente Magsafe, both with L shape, and I was asking whether both are compatible with my specific laptop model, since in their table different laptop models are listed with the two items I'm mentioning: what is unclear exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, any Magsafe 1 charger will work. With that said, due to the unique shape of the original MacBook Air, it won't rest flat unless you use the charger that can with it. So you actually don't want *any* of the chargers shown on that page, you want one [like this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/APPLE-OEM-MagSafe-45W-AC-ADAPTER-POWER-CHARGER-A1244-MACBOOK-AIR-11-13-2008-2009-/331753169150?hash=item4d3e07a0fe:g:FoAAAOSwYIhWlcjb). Notice the different angle on the charger head. With that said, since Apple doesn't sell official ones any more, be very careful to make sure that you get an authentic one: knock-offs can **actually destroy your computer**.

To my knowledge, there's no Magsafe 2 to Magsafe 1 adapter (someone else showed a Magsafe 1 to Magsafe 2 adapter which will do nothing for you.) Even if there was, there's no good reason to get one unless you already have Magsafe 1 chargers and then buy a new MacBook with Magsafe 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's precisely the kind of information I was looking for. So can you confirm that in the picture "Computers that use the 45W MagSafe Adapter" in the page that I linked above, only the first one is compatible with my laptop, although Apple does not sell it anymore and recommends to use the second one? Can you recommend other places where I could look for it, besides Amazon and Ebay? Moreover, do you know some place where I could buy just the DC power cord, but an original one and suitable for my model?

Comment: @jj_p Yeah, the first 45W Magsafe is what you want. Afraid I don't know anywhere besides eBay, and it's unlikely that anyone is selling only the DC part: my guess is that they'll be selling both together.

Answer (score -1):

The two original magsafe (4-pin) connectors will fit any Magsafe 1; that is, the [straight white connector (left), and the L-shaped stainless steel (right)](http://www.macservice.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/magsafe_adapters.jpg).

I'm assuming they changed the design for two reasons, one, the white ones didn't match the newer stainless steel design, and two, it sticks out more than the L-shaped version.

Magsafe2 uses a 5-pin connector.  You can buy a [converter](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Apple/MD504LLA/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=shoppingengine&utm_campaign=googlebase&gclid=CNWX8_Pw6MoCFcIRHwod4hMIDw) that will adapt 1 -> 2.